# What port is used in OS X for remote desktop?

Tags: macos, router

I want to set forwarding IP address on a router.
What port is used in OS X for remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be the same port than VNC server, 5900.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Maybe the problem is in another.